# Continuous functions on disconnected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

I am having some problems solving the following exercise from a supplement to Rudin’s “Principle of Mathematical Analysis”:

> “If $ \{ E_i \}_{i \in I} $ is a family of at least two pairwise disjoint subsets of a metric space X whose union is all of X, and such that every function $ f:X \rightarrow Y $ such that the restriction of $f$ to each $E_i$ is continuous, is itself continuous, then all $E_i$ are open.”

Any hint is highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

After some thought I found this solution:
"*Suppose that $E_{i*}$ isn't open, then, by definition, there exists a point $x_0 \in E_{i*}$ such that every neighbourhood of $x_0$ contains at least a point of the X-complement of $E_{i*}$. Now, let $\{ x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be the sequence of points of the X-complement of $E_{i*}$ such that $x_n$ is at a distance at most $\frac1n$ from $x_0$. Finally, define a function $f: X \rightarrow R$ such that $f(x) = 0, \forall x \notin E_{i*}$ and $f(x) = 1, \forall x \in E_{i*}$. Clearly this function is continuous on each set of the collection $\{ E_i \}_{i \in I}$, however, $f(x_n)$ can not approach 1 because it is constantly 0, thus contradicting the hypotesis*"

Any proof-check/-review is welcome!

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Actually I am posting an attempt to solution in a few moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought I found this solution:
"*Suppose that $E_{i*}$ isn't open, then, by definition, there exists a point $x_0 \in E_{i*}$ such that every neighbourhood of $x_0$ contains at least a point of the X-complement of $E_{i*}$. Now, let $\{ x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be the sequence of points of the X-complement of $E_{i*}$ such that $x_n$ is at a distance at most $\frac1n$ from $x_0$. Finally, define a function $f: X \rightarrow R$ such that $f(x) = 0, \forall x \notin E_{i*}$ and $f(x) = 1, \forall x \in E_{i*}$. Clearly this function is continuous on each set of the collection $\{ E_i \}_{i \in I}$, however, $f(x_n)$ can not approach 1 because it is constantly 0, thus contradicting the hypotesis*"

Comment: +1. However, I found the Q confusing as it not say "for $every$ $Y$". BTW continuity of $f:X\to Y$ is equivalent to $\forall A\subseteq X\,(\,f[Cl_X(A)]\subseteq Cl_Y(f[A])\,).$ So you can re-phrase it as: Let $A=X\setminus E_{i*}$ with $x_0\in E_{i*}\cap \overline A.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Actually, in the original question it said “for any metric space Y” so I think it should be okay, anyway, thanks for the observation!

Comment: The re-phrasing that I suggested shows that it holds for any topological space $X$. BTW there are many consequences of continuity of a function that are in fact equivalent to continuity, & some of them are better than others for certain problems.